# javascript countdown timer every 3 hours using server time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a countdown to my site and what I want is every 3 hours the countdown will reset to 3 hours.

it goes like this:
start countdown - 12mn(00:00:01) as 2:60:59 and end countdown - 3am as 0:00:00
then it will start again - 3am(03:00:01) as 2:60:59, end countdown 6am: 0:00:00 etc... and get the server time not local machine time.

I was able to make it in PHP and here's the code

from my controller

```
function timer(){
    $time = time(); 
    $sincelaststart = $time % (2 * 60 * 60);
    $untilnextcount = 2 * 60 * 60 - $sincelaststart;
    echo date('H:i:s', $untilnextcount);
}
```

from my display

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $('#countdown').load("<?php echo base_url('test/timer'); ?>");
    }, 1000); 
</script>

<span id="countdown"></span>
```

what I'm trying to do now is pure javascript.
And so far I got this line code run, but it's giving me too much time in loading the page.

```
  (function() {
var date = new Date();
var currenthours = date.getHours();
var currentminutes = date.getMinutes();
var currentseconds = date.getSeconds();


var start = new Date;


if(currenthours >= 21 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(24, 0, 0); // 12mn
}else if(currenthours >= 18 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(21, 0, 0); // 9pm
}else if(currenthours >= 15 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(18, 0, 0); // 6pm
}else if(currenthours >= 12 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(15, 0, 0); // 3pm
}else if(currenthours >= 9 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(12, 0, 0); // 12nn
}else if(currenthours >= 6 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(9, 0, 0); // 9am
}else if(currenthours >= 3 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(6, 0, 0); // 6am
}else if(currenthours >= 0 && currentminutes > 0 && currentseconds>0){
  start.setHours(3, 0, 0); // 3am
}



  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    // if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
    //   start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    // }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('lbnextwar').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    if(hh==0 && mm==0 && ss==0){
      start.setHours(start.getHours() + 3);
    }
    if((hh==0 && mm==0 && ss==0) || (hh==2 && mm>=40 && ss>=0)){
        $('#nationmatch').show();
    }else{
        $('#nationmatch').hide();
    }

    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why so many hits to server every second? Just send the start and end timestamp from server to js. Then use js only to loop(setTimeout) untill its timeout. On timeout get next lapse from server.

Comment: that is why I'm asking for help for javascript code, since I'm not used to javascript. I want to make the auto refresh on the page itself not in the server side.

Comment: can you help me with this code, instead of every hour, make it every 3 hours. 
var st = srvTime();
            now1 = new Date(st);
            mins = now1.getMinutes();
            secs = now1.getSeconds();
            document.f1.t1.value = 60 * 60 - (mins * 60 + secs);

Comment: are you having trouble with the counter itself or with displaying it ?

Comment: Never mind answering this question! I was able to solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the php part from javascript code and it just worked  fine

```
<html>
<body>
<span id="countdown"></span>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $('#countdown').load('test/timer.php');
    }, 1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: what?! that's not going to work, lol still code are still getting data from $('#countdown').load('test/timer.php');

Comment: no, i wanna do it full in javascript. try to inspect element and go to network it will call the controller tesrt/timer.php every seconds and that's what I want to removed.

Comment: but you said you want to the server time , you wont be able to do this without php unless if you want to change it with server side javascript framework like nodejs

Comment: please read "I want is every 3 hours the countdown will reset to 3:00:00."

Comment: what about this ? _and get the server time not local machine time._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157715/discussion-between-soltani-neji-and-dennis).